# Access Laravel URL with ID only

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5, logic

My application is made in laravel 5.8, I want to ask about the best approach for a unique scenario where I want to display some of my customer profiles like

**https://www.example.com/1234**

I know that in laravel I have to give a unique identifier before the URL like **https://www.example.com/profile/1234** so that it know which function to look for. But for some reason I have to build the above URL.

I tried it directly like:

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'ExampleController@myfunction')->name('profiler');
```

But this only works when I put it in bottom of my Routes file. If I place it somewhere in the middle or top. All other links like **https://www.example.com/about-us** stops working.

My Question is:

- What is the best way to achieve something like this. (Is it fine
  that I keep it in the bottom of the route file or will it be some
  kind of threat or any drawbacks to this approach?)
- Should I use this approach or add a unique identifier instead.

I would really want to use the URL I mentioned in the start of the question.

Thank you all in advance for helping me.

Peace :)

Comment: Take a look at the [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can specify the type of {id} through regular expression.

```
Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
//
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

this route will only work if **id** is numeric for

```
https://www.example.com/about-us
```

it the route will not work.

hope that's what you are looking for..

Comment: This is a good answer. I can form a regex for alphanumeric characters right?

Comment: Yes anything in regrex.. that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You will indeed have to place this route at the end of the route list. This is because it will match *any* route that starts with the base URL. Your route requires an `id` path parameter, but this will match `about-us` as well.

The route without any path parameter, e.g. just `/`, won't be matched by this rule since `id` is required.

Comment: If I put it at the bottom of the routes file, Are there any drawbacks to this?

Comment: It will be a catch-all for all routes not matched by routes declared above it, but it won't interfere with the URL of the web application itself as it requires a trailing `/` followed by a non-empty value.